# How do I make \titleformat not apply for Appendix?

Tags: formatting, fontsize, appendices

I have a simple LaTeX code.

I want to use a particular section format only for the appendix section. But, it have a conflict with `\titleformat{\section}`.

If I run the following code, *Appendix*: shows up in the title of `appendix` section.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  %It can be article / report / and book 
\usepackage{amsmath}


\usepackage{titlesec}

%\titleformat{\section}    
%       {\fontsize{14}{10}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}    
       {\fontsize{12}{5}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}    
       {\fontsize{12}{5}\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

%% Set up some preparatory code -- activated fully after '\appendix'
%% (see 'The LaTeX Companion,' 2nd. ed., pp. 26f. for more details)
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%      default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}%    enable individual control
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Counting words} 
\appendix
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\makeatletter 
% "activate" the preparatory code, but for section-level headers only
\newcommand{\section@cntformat}{Appendix \thesection:\ }
\makeatother

\section{Counting words without repetitions} 

\begin{equation} a^2+b^2=c^2 \end{equation}

\subsection{afdf}
\end{document}
```

But if I make the following part of code work, *Appendix* doesn't show up.

```
%\titleformat{\section}    
%       {\fontsize{14}{10}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

Is there any way to control overall font size and show `Appendix` at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you overwrite the solution you applied from the LaTeX companion when you use titlesec's command. As you have it

```
\titleformat{\section}
 {\fontsize{14}{10}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

will redefine the printing of the counter from being `\@seccntformat` to directly using `\thesection`.

All you need to do is change it to

```
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}
 {\fontsize{14}{10}\bfseries}{\@seccntformat{section}}{1em}{}
\makeatother
```

and you're back in business

Comment: What is the equivalent of \@seccntformat if what we are using chapters?

Answer (score 1):

You simply can use the `\IfAppendix` command from the `apptools` package within `\titleformat`.  B.t.w., in `\fontsize`, the second argument (for the base line skip) should be about 20-25% more than the first (the font size):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} %It can be article / report / and book \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{apptools}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
 {\fontsize{14}{10}\bfseries}{\IfAppendix{\appendixname}{} \thesection}{1em}{}
%
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Counting words}

\appendix \numberwithin{equation}{section}

\section{Counting words without repetitions}

\begin{equation} a^2+b^2=c^2 \end{equation}

\subsection{afdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]